# Jeknins pipeline Global Vars - return a variable from a shell script, then export it into a shell script

Tags: groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I need to split a git tag by dashes.  Here is an example of the data:

`DEVQA-10000000-6d26fa05def3fa94a2acd0ca12fcdd6a82fc46d7-SUCCESS`

This should split as $1-$2-$3-$4

My idea was to use awk `git tag -l | grep DEVQA |  awk -F '[ -]' '{print $1}'` for instance.

I tried defining using withEnvs, i tried getting the values in another script and loading it into mine i.e. load 'env/file'

I cant seem to figure it out.  It prints the commands as the pipeline run s

```
stage('Build ') {
def buildRecordId = sh(script: "git tag -l | grep DEVQA | awk -F \'[ -]\' \'{print \$2}\'", returnStdout: true).trim() as Integer
def startRev = sh(script: "git tag -l | grep DEVQA | awk -F \'[ -]\' \'{print \$3}\'", returnStdout: true).trim()
def testlevel="noLocalTests"
sh """ export testlevel="${testlevel}";
export startrevision="${env.startRev}";
export buildrecordid="${env.buildRecordId}";
echo "I worked: $startrevision";
/tools/ant/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant  -verbose -buildfile ./buildtool/build.xml -propertyfile ./buildtool/build.properties.hc.inc.dev startCICD
            """
                    }
```

And of course it doesnt find startrevision:

"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: startrevision for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier in pure Groovy and using the intrinsic for a git tag instead of executing shell commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used triple double quote string in `sh` step, which will do string interpolation before execute the bash inside `sh` step. Read detail at [here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings)

String interpolation will try to replace `${ABC}` or `$ABC` with value of groovy variable `ABC`.

Your error says it fail to find groovy variable `startrevision` when doing interpolation.

If `startrevision` intend to be a bash environment variable, you need to escape the `$` by `\$`, if a groovy variable, please define and assign value to it.

```
echo "I worked: \$startrevision";
```